# How can Data.IntMap.Strict be kept strict after a traversal?

Tags: haskell

[Data.IntMap.Strict docs say](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-IntMap-Strict.html):

> Be aware that the Functor, Traversable and Data instances are the same
>   as for the Data.IntMap.Lazy module, so if they are used on strict
>   maps, the resulting maps will be lazy.

I use `IntMap.traverseWithKey` (`Functor f => Applicative f`) because I want a `mapWithKey` and a `maprWithKey` which doesn't exist. Instead I use the `Backwards` functor on a strict map. How can I keep the map strict after an Applicative use?

Comment: You can use `mapAccumWithKey` and `mapAccumRWithKey`. Just ignore the accumulator.

Comment: @AndrásKovács and just have an unused accumulator?

Comment: As I understand you want to use `traverseWithKey` at the type `Applicative t => (Key -> a -> Backwards t b) -> IntMap a -> Backwards t (IntMap b)`. The `Applicative (Backwards f)` instance should be as strict as the `Applicative f` instance because Backwards is a newtype. And traverseWithKey is the same for lazy and strict maps anyways, so you should have no issues. Note that this won't traverse the IntMap structure in the opposite order, only the effects of the applicative instance will be composed in the opposite order. You may be looking for `mapAccumRWithKey`.

Comment: @user2407038 yeah you're right. Visiting in the reverse order is a performance optimization that I'm not getting with Backwards. Either way I need to do what you and András Kovács are suggesting. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrásKovács put your comment as an answer and I'll mark it answered.

Comment: BTW, why would you need `maprWithKey`? Without effects or accumulators the order of mapping is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @AndrásKovács after looking at my code again I forgot to mention a key piece of information: I'm mapping a monadic function which is why I was using traverse in the first place. I'm looking now to see if I can decompose the monads into an accum but it looks messy.

Comment: @LukeHoersten see my edit in the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mapAccumWithKey` and `mapAccumRWithKey`, without using the accumulator argument. After optimization it's most likely exactly as fast as a `mapWithKey` function would be.

EDIT: if you're doing monadic traversals, and would like to make the possibly resulting `IntMap`-s strict, then you can achieve that by returning strict values inside the monadic action.

```
import Data.IntMap.Strict
import Control.Applicative

m :: IntMap Int
m = fromList $ zip [0..] (replicate 10 0)
```

`traverse (\n -> Just (n + 100)) m` returns a `Just m` map that contains `n + 100` thunks. `traverse (\n -> Just $! n + 100) m` returns a map containing evaluated `Int`-s. Likewise, use `return $! x` in other monads to get strict results.